# Laravel App on AWS. 503 Error

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently deployed a Laravel App to an Elastic Beanstalk php 7.1 environment. When I did the deploy everything seems to have gone well (there were no deploy errors) and when I checked the logs composer seems to have been able to install all dependencies properly.

Whenever I try to navigate to the URL of the environment I am greeted with a 503 error which I do not understand. When I check the httpd error log I see:

```
FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
```

I don't know if this is the cause of the 503 error but I am unable to understand how to handle this error as in Elastic Beanstalk there is not all that much control over Apache or the PHP installation. Help?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue as well on my core PHP application. Troubleshooting to find the issue. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Same problem here, does anyone know why it fails?

Comment: Can you access the machine over ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my application the answer was to move back down to the phone v7.0 image. I don't know why but something in the 7.1 image was not working properly.